# What can I do for merge nothing back from release branch to develop branch

Tags: git, version-control, merge

[image: git workflow[1]]

I have flow the git workflow of this picture.

Now I have some specifical changes on release branch which should not merge back to develop branch. then how can I flow this git workflow?

because as this picture mentioned, I should merge the changes on release branch back to develop branch whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would merge all changes to the development branch and the [revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) them to undo the changes.

That way you will have all changes done on the release branch merged and ready to merge future changes as well.

Revert takes one commit as argument and creates a new commit that undo all the changes in the original commit.

```
git revert <commit>
```

Comment: sounds good, only one question for this: if in release branch I have delete some files, like some localization files, which means maybe in some release I don't need those language support at that release.  And after merge back and do the revert, do I some kind of lose the change log for those files? since it's kind of remove a file and add a file again.

Comment: You will not lose the history but you'll show up on all lines if you do `git blame` since you added all those lines last.